# Python win32: error

Tags: python, pywin32

I am trying to make python script run as a windows service.

Just to have a little understanding, I have taken this code from [here](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/windows_services_in_python).

I have installed the following things:

1. python2.7 (64 bit)
2. pywin32.exe. (64 bit)

However, the script is not able to find the following things:

1. win32event.CreateEvent
2. win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0
3. win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)
4. win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
5. win32event.SetEvent

Though I am not getting any error messages for import but I am getting error messages for the aforementioned functions.

```
import win32service  
import win32serviceutil  
import win32event  

class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):  
# you can NET START/STOP the service by the following name  
_svc_name_ = "PySvc"  
# this text shows up as the service name in the Service  
# Control Manager (SCM)  
_svc_display_name_ = "Python Test Service"  
# this text shows up as the description in the SCM  
_svc_description_ = "This service writes stuff to a file"  

def __init__(self, args):  
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)  
    # create an event to listen for stop requests on  
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)  

# core logic of the service     
def SvcDoRun(self):  
    import servicemanager  

    f = open('test.dat', 'w+')  
    rc = None  

    # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping  
    while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:  
        f.write('TEST DATA\n')  
        f.flush()  
        # block for 5 seconds and listen for a stop event  
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)  

    f.write('SHUTTING DOWN\n')  
    f.close()  

# called when we're being shut down      
def SvcStop(self):  
    # tell the SCM we're shutting down  
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)  
    # fire the stop event  
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reinstall win32 from sourceforge.net site. But it didn't work out.

Finally I tried the pip command, and it worked like charm.

```
pip install pypiwin32
```